# Composition of onto and one-to-one functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Question : Let f: X → Y and g: Y → Z be two functions.
Is it possible that f is not onto and g ο f is onto? Justify your answer. If the answer is "yes", give a specific example for f and g.

Not possible because in that case, for g ο f, at least one element il the domain won't be mapped. Is that right?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(x)=(x,0)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x,y)=x$. The composite is the identity, which is onto.

You can't prevent surjectivity of the composition by just having restrictions on the first function, as you can always take $Z$ as the image of $g$ and ensure surjectivity.

Answer (score 1):

No.  $g$ could map two points to the same point, and then $f$ could miss one of those points and the composition still be onto.

Here's an example:   $f:I\hookrightarrow  [-1,1]$ by $f(x)=x$ (the so-called inclusion), and $g: [-1,1]\to I$ by $g(x)=x^2$.  Here $I=[0,1]$.

If you restrict $g$ to being 1-1,  *then* the answer is no.